# Mouse handling: printing pixel location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, callback, mouseevent

I've been trying to do some work with OpenCV in VS2010, specifically in the area of mouse handling.  So far, I have this:

```
CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN
        :drawing_line = true;
        cvLine( frame, cvPoint(x,y),cvPoint(350,500), CV_RGB(255,0,0), CV_AA, 15,0 );
        fprintf( stdout, "Point found. %i, %i \n", object_x0, object_y0 );
        break;
```

What I want it to do is return the location of the pixels that I clicked on but all it returns is "Point found. 0,0" instead of the actual location. Eventually, I would like to use the points with cvLine to draw a line but right now I would just like to get some values returned to me.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is `object_x0` and `object_y0` ?

Comment: see `OpenCV2.2\samples\cpp\camshiftdemo.cpp`

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the position of a mouse-click by passing it as the parameter to the mouse callback function like so:

```
void onMouse(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {
    if(evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        cv::Point* ptPtr = (cv::Point*)param;
        ptPtr->x = x;
        ptPtr->y = y;
    }
}

int main() {
    cv::Point2i pt(-1,-1);
    cv::namedWindow("Output Window");
    frame = cv::imread("image.jpg");
    cv::imshow(winName, frame);

    cv::setMouseCallback(winName, onMouse, (void*)&pt);
    // Note that we passed '&pt' (a pointer
    // to `pt`) to the mouse callback function.
    // Therefore `pt` will update its [x,y] coordinates
    // whenever user left-clicks on the image in "Output Window".
}
```

Comment: Thank you for code example, but How can we see where the mouse is clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

Points are passed in as arguments to the Mouse callback function.

```
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
```

You'll want to save those x, y into a global when you click down, then a different global when you click up, then draw a line between the two.