# setMouseCallback passing coordinates to main function

Tags: c++, opencv

I realize that there are a bunch of questions out there related to what I am about to ask, but I am still having some troubles getting everything to work together. I am fairly new to C++ and OpenCV so please excuse me if me question is obvious.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is:
   1. Open an image
   2. Get the user to click on a point on the image
   3. Create a region of interest around the place where the user has clicked
   4. Perform corner or feature detection in that region of interest

Right now I am having troubles with 3. I am trying to use setMouseCallback inside my main function to grab the coordinates of the pixel that the user has chosen. I have tried using something of the form:

```
void mouseHandler( int e, int x, int y, int d, void *ptr){
    Point*p = (Point*)ptr;
    p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
}

int main() {
    Point p;
    namedWindow("window");
    Mat image = imread("cam3_10.tif");
    imshow("window",image);

    setMouseCallback("window",mouseHandler, &p ); 

    cout <<p;

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I use pointers in this form, I am not sure how to get the updated value of p the next time that the mouse button is pressed.

I read in another place that this might be remedied by creating a class. I tried modeling off of [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781622/opencv-2-3-with-vs-2008-mouse-events)

Right now I am trying to do something like the following:
All I want to be able to show is that the value for p is being updated whenever a mouse event occurs. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat frame;
Point p;

class ROIPoint {
    Point ROI, guess;
public:
    static void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param) {
        if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN){
            Point*p = (Point*)param;
            p->x = x;
            p->y = y;
        }
    }
};

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
   frame = imread("cam3_10.tif",1);
   char* name = "Frame";
   namedWindow( name, 0 );
   imshow("Frame",frame);
   ROIPoint obj;
   setMouseCallback(name, obj.mouseHandler,&p);

   cout << p <<endl;


   waitKey(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I did misunderstand you.  You don't need a class for this.

If you want to call your OpenCV functions every single time there's a mouse event, call them from `mouseHandler()`.  If you want to call them on your own schedule, do it in `main()`.  Since you passed `p` by reference (the & symbol), it will always hold the most recent mouse information.  Your problem was that you were printing `p` only once.

---

> > All I want to be able to show is that the value for p is being updated whenever a mouse event occurs.

Unless I'm misunderstanding you, wouldn't it be enough to move your `cout` into `mouseHandler()`?  You could also move `p` into `ROIPoint` and call `setMouseCallback()` in the constructor.  Then you wouldn't even need to pass `p` in as `param`.

By the way, OpenCV has their own Q&A forum: http://answers.opencv.org/

Comment: Then a class isn't necessary - just put your cout in the `mouseHandler()` of your first example so you can see that `p` is being updated.

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks so much for your speedy reply. I see what you are saying now. I was trying to do everything backwards. Really I would like mouseHandler to be calling the next functions that will be doing processing on the pixel location and not the other way around. In this case the code is indeed doing what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: That depends on if you really want to call your functions every time there's a mouse event.  You can still call your functions from `main()` and `p` will hold the latest mouse information.  Your problem was that you were printing `p` only once.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15070442/1121420), the answer does exactly what you are asking for.  You don't need to wrap the callback function into a class.